# I have 5 pages.When firstly drag up page one and swip pages to 3 drag up, is works and then go back to page 1 and drag up , It says null pointer error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, motionevent, android-motionlayout

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wSxb.jpg)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjkfx.jpg)

> Viewpager item can drag up like picture. And now I have 5 item for
> viewpager. if drag up item one and swip go to item 3, I don not
> problem. And go back again for item 1. İtem one will be start
> position. And it can be drag up or down. but then swip viewpager to
> item two and drag up, app produce error null pointer.
>
> ```
> This is my view_pager_item
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_container">
            <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
            <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
                android:id="@+id/motion_lay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:background="@color/grimsi"
                        android:id="@+id/header_image"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/content_layout"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                         <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/apod_image"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/deneme2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >
    
                        </ImageView>
   
                    </RelativeLayout>
 
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:background="@color/grimsi"
                        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
                        <ScrollView
                            android:paddingBottom="40dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_bottom_right_left"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"   
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                                <TextView
                                    android:textColor="@color/siyahimsi"
                                    android:id="@+id/apod_content"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/lora"
                                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                                    android:textSize="17sp"
                                    android:paddingEnd="32dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
                                    android:text="Explanation:"
                                    app:lineHeight="26dp" />
    
                            </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
    
                    </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
                        android:elevation="50dp"
                        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/header_image"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_top_right_left"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_drag_handle_24"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center">
    
                        </ImageView>
                        <TextView
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
    
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_right_left"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/apod_tarih_txt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:padding="12dp"
                            android:text="13.10.2020"
                            android:textColor="@color/grimsi2"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                        <View
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_right_left_gradient" />
    
                        <TextView
    
                            android:id="@+id/apod_header_txt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_right_left"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="12dp"
                            android:text="Mars, Pleiades, and Andromeda over Stone Lions"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:textSize="22sp" />
                        <View
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_right_left_gradient" />
                        <TextView
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_bold"
                            android:textStyle="italic"
    
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_right_left"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:id="@+id/apod_name_txt"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:padding="12dp"
                            android:text="Cem Özkeser"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
    
            </RelativeLayout>
    
        </FrameLayout>
   
        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> this is my Java code (Mainactivity)

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IFirebaseLoadDone {
        private NavigationView navigationView;
        private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
        private androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
        
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private DatabaseReference databaseReference, ResimlerDatabase;
        private String currentUserID;
        private ImageView imageView;
        MotionScene motionScene;
            private ViewPager viewPager;
        private com.e.apod2.Adapter.Adapter mAdapter;
        IFirebaseLoadDone iFirebaseLoadDone;
            List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
            MotionLayout motionLayout;
            VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        
                ResimlerDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Contents");
                motionLayout = findViewById(R.id.motion_lay);
        
        
                //init event
                iFirebaseLoadDone = this;
        
                loadContent();
                imageView = findViewById(R.id.resmibuyut);
                viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        
                viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
             drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.draw_lay);
               actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this , drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
               drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        
                navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
                toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
                actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
               actionBarDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                        UserMenuSelector(menuItem);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
        
        
              imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      int position =  viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                      String s= modelList.get(position).getImage().toString();
                      String baslik1= modelList.get(position).getHeader().toString();
                      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FullScreenImage.class);
                      i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", s);
                      i.putExtra("baslik" , baslik1);
                      startActivity(i);
                  }
              });
            
            }
         
        
            private void loadContent() {
        
                ResimlerDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            modelList.add(0,dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model.class));
                            iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadDone(modelList);
                            int i = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(i-1);
        
                    }
        
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadFailed(databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        
            private void KullaniciOlustur() {
                currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
        
                HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                hashMap.put("username", "engin");
                databaseReference.updateChildren(hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "veritabanı kaydedildi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        
                @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                UpdateUI(currentUser);
        
        
                super.onStart();
            }
        
            private void UpdateUI(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
        
                if (currentUser == null){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "kullanıcı yok ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        
                    mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                KullaniciOlustur();
                                UpdateUI(user);
                            }else{
                                UpdateUI(null);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        
        
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, mAuth.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
                   
       }
```

> here is my errror
>
> E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
> E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
> E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.view.VelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(int)' on a null
> object reference
> at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout$MyTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(MotionLayout.java:1098)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.TouchResponse.processTouchEvent(TouchResponse.java:270)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionScene.processTouchEvent(MotionScene.java:1328)
> at androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout.onTouchEvent(MotionLayout.java:3462)